# with or without [weak self]

Tags: swift

I have a very strange situation. My server is currently down and getting 503 http status code.
Based on the given code as follows, code gets into the if condition and but when I put debug point to the `let error = self?.decodeErrorMessage(data: data, statusCode: response.statusCode)`. then it is jumping from if condition and executes the else if condition.

**ClientViewModel.swift**

```
let networkRequest = CustomNetworkRequest(headers: headers, httpMethod: .get, httpBody: nil, parameters: nil, url: url)

let customNetworker = CustomNetworker(urlSession: URLSession(configuration: config))
  customNetworker.dataRequest(networkRequest, successHandler: {[weak self] data in
    self?.parseData(data)
    completion(nil)
  }, failureHandler: { [weak self] error in
    completion(error)
})
```

**CustomNetworker.swift**

```
final class CustomNetworker {
  private let urlSession: URLSession

  public init(urlSession: URLSession) {
    self.urlSession = urlSession
  }
  func dataRequest(input parameters here) {
    let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {[weak self] data, response, error in
     if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse , 300...599 ~= response.statusCode,
     let data = data,
     let error = self?.decodeErrorMessage(data: data, statusCode: response.statusCode) {
    failureHandler(error)
    } else if let error = error {
     failureHandler(error)
    } else if let data = data {
      successHandler(data)
    } else {
      failureHandler(error)
    }
  }
  task.resume()
  }
}
```

However, If I remove `[weak self]` then it works as expected, it calls that method. How should I resolve the issue properly?

```
let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {data, response, error in
  if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse , 300...599 ~= response.statusCode,
    let data = data,
    let error = self.decodeErrorMessage(data: data, statusCode: response.statusCode) {
    failureHandler(error)
  }
  else if let error = error {
    failureHandler(error)
  } else if let data = data {
    successHandler(data)
  } else {
    failureHandler(error)
    )
  }
}
task.resume()
```

**decodeErrorMessage** method

```
private func decodeErrorMessage(data: Data, statusCode: Int) -> CustomError?  {
   // not coming into this method
    if let errorData = try? JSONDecoder.convertFromSnakeCaseDecoder.decode(CustomServiceError.self, from: data) as CustomServiceError? {
      if let errorData = errorData {
        return formCustomError(something here)
      }
      return CustomError.genericError(debugMessage: debugMessage, sourceError: nil)
    } else if let errorMessage = StatusCode(rawValue: statusCode) {
      let debugMessage = String(data:data, encoding: .utf8)
      return formCustomError(something here)
    } else {
      let debugMessage = String(data:data, encoding: .utf8)
      return formCustomError(something here)
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does "resolve the issue properly" mean? Are you asking about the breakpoint _debugging_ behavior or why the actual _method_ is not working?

Comment: Actually, it has started calling that method once I remove the `[weak self]`. the actually method works as expected. But if I put [weak self], this method is not getting called.

Comment: Yes but you can't necessarily do that. And that doesn't solve the problem, it just ignores the problem.

Comment: That is what I am wondering the root of the problem, and looking for experts opinion and suggestions.

Comment: Yes but I'm asking you what "problem" you mean. I can't give an answer until you clarify exactly what the question is about.

Comment: I put a debug point     `let error = self?.decodeErrorMessage(data: data, statusCode: response.statusCode) {` at this line, even though I have data and statusCode is 503 as Int, but not calling that method.

Comment: In general, by the way, you should do the "weak-strong dance". The first thing in your completion handler should be `guard let self = self else { return }`. That way you don't need `self?` throughout, and the code doesn't even try to execute if `self` has vanished in the meantime.

Comment: So you _are_ asking about how to use the debugger?

Comment: I put a debug point inside the `decodeErrorMessage()`, but not hitting there as it is expected.

Comment: I have added `guard let self = self else { return }` in the urlSession.dataTask and just simply goes into else condition and `return`.

Comment: Well the implication is that `self` is indeed going out of existence. But you have not told us what `self` even is or how it is created, stored, or used, so I cannot give you any more information. I have given that as an answer, but that's all I can do given the lack of relevant information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you’ve made `customNetworker`, the `CustomNetworker`, a local variable and you lose your strong reference to it as soon as this local variable falls out of scope. When the `dataRequest(input:)` method uses a `[weak self]` reference, it’s saying that you don’t want `dataRequest(input:)` to keep a strong reference to this `CustomNetworker` instance, either. As a result, with no strong references, the `CustomNetworker` will be deallocated.

You have a few alternatives:

1. If you remove the `[weak self]` reference in the closure inside `dataRequest(input:)`, then it will retain the `CustomNetworker` until the closure runs. As long as you don’t save this `failureHandler` (and other closures) as stored properties, you should be fine. But don’t just throw in a `[weak self]` because you read somewhere that you should always use weak references. Use weak references where you need to avoid strong reference cycles, which would not appear to be the case here.
2. The other alternative is to refactor this code, moving this network request routine, `dataRequest(input:)` to some more long-lived object.

   E.g., we often have a long-lived network manager object that maintains the `URLSession` and has all these network related methods. Then, assuming you’re keeping a strong reference to this network manager instance elsewhere, you don’t need to worry about the object being deallocated when it falls out of scope. This also saves you from having to pass in the `URLSession` object for every request. A caller should not be dealing with these `URLSession` instances, anyway.

   For example, I often use a singleton network layer (kind of equivalent to `URLSession.shared` pattern):

   ```swift
   final class NetworkManager {
       static let shared = NetworkManager()

       private var session: URLSession = .shared // or create and configure this session as you need; but one session object is all you need

       private init() { }

       @discardableResult
       func performRequest(...) -> URLSessionTask {
           ...
           let task = session.dataTask(...) { [weak self] data, response, error in
               ...
           }
           task.resume()
           return task
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can do things like:

   ```swift
   NetworkManager.shared.performRequest(...) { [weak self] ... in
       ...
   }
   ```
3. The other alternative is to just keep a strong reference to this `customNetworker` variable (e.g. make it a property rather than a local variable). That will prevent the `CustomNetworker` object from falling out of scope and becoming `nil` because there are no more strong references to it.

---

Somewhat unrelated, but it would appear that you are creating a `URLSession` object when you instantiate your `CustomNetworker` object, and subsequently never invalidate it. This will leak. You should create a single `URLSession` object and use it for all subsequent network requests.

If you do create multiple `URLSession` objects, you must invalidate each one when you’re done with it (e.g., [`finishTasksAndInvalidate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407428-finishtasksandinvalidate)), or else you will leak. But if you just have one session that you keep alive for all future network requests (which is preferred), then that is not necessary.

Comment: Rob, thank you so much for all great explanation. Would you mind to illustrate one of your suggestion please?

Comment: The simple solution is to remove the `[weak self]` reference and you’re done. That having been said, I would pursue option 2.

Comment: By the way, thank you so much for extra information.

Comment: @Rob off topic, you might have some knowledge about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66051129/confused-about-operation-and-operationqueue-qos-relationship

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that whatever `self` is, it is some object that you have not retained properly, so it goes out of existence before the networking can happen. When you remove `weak self` you create a sort of retain cycle that keeps this object alive, but this merely masks the problem. You should be concentrating on how `self` is created and retained and why it is going out of existence so quickly.

Comment: I added the missing piece in the question. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, that makes it obvious. Rob's answer is excellent of course.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to set break point inside expression. You have if statement with a complex expression and trying to set break point inside it and trace if one of sub expression is true / or false. If you would like to debug it then you need to divide it in several if statements.

Comment: I have updated my question with my findings.